# JSON.Net insecure deserialization

Tags: exploit, deserialization

I have a question in regard to insecure deserialization with the JSON.Net component.
It is my understanding that this component is safe by default unless you specify the `TypeNameHandling` setting to anything except for `none`.

However, suppose you do not change the `TypeNameHandling` setting (so that the default applies), will the following implementation be vulnerable to insecure deserialization (for instance, to achieve RCE)?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonModelFromUserinput)
```

I'm only able to create RCE when the default `TypeNameHandling` setting is changed.

Comment: This answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038055/external-json-vulnerable-because-of-json-net-typenamehandling-auto

Comment: Thank you. It helped me further.

Comment: Goodness gracious. The best part about JSON is that it's simplicity means that parsing libraries have far less to worry about when it comes to application vulnerabilities. A tool where you have to worry about RCE when decoding JSON is just stupid...